# How do i Connect PC Internet on Android Mobile?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internet

**About My Phone:**

Model Name: Asus Zenfone 5 ( Rooted )

Version: Lolliop 5.0

**About My Laptop:**

Model Name: B460e

OS: Windows 8

Not Having Wifi and Bluetooth.

I used Broadband connection for my laptop.

I am already tried "**Reverse Tethering**" and "**Easy Tether Lite**". These method 
is not suitable for my phone.

How can i connect my laptop internet to my android mobile?

Comment: Are you sure your laptop does not have a wifi adapter? I haven't seen one without. Try setting up a WiFi-hotspot on your laptop and connect to it from your phone (that definitely has a WiFi adapter).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Connectify](https://www.connectify.me/blog/how-to/create-wifi-hotspot-windows-7-computer/) software. I had recently [put up a thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/turning-a-desktop-pc-into-a-wifi-hotspot-using-connectify-software.972629/) on a different site. My PC too doesn't have a WiFi module. My proposal was to use an external USB WiFi module, and then turn that into a hotspot. People in Physics Forums (check the second link) have said that in principle, this should be possible.